# OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am using Opencv in android and I want to load an image from gallery to Mat , please check my code and help in what I did wrong?

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        String selectedImagePath = getPath(imageUri);

    Mat imgRgba = Imgcodecs.imread( selectedImagePath );
    Mat img = new Mat();
    imgRgba.copyTo(img);
   }

private String getPath(Uri imageUri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( imageUri, projection, null, null, null );
    if(cursor!=null){
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA );
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString( column_index );

    }

    return imageUri.getPath();
}
```

When I run it it crashes with : 
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_11 and Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_11__Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:118)`

Comment: How can someone figure out: "what I did wrong"? Without getting to know the issue you are facing? Are you getting an empty `Mat`? Are you getting an exception? Are you getting image of Justin Bieber, while reading `Lena.png`?

Comment: sorry the app crashes in this line `Mat imgRgba = Imgcodecs.imread( selectedImagePath );`    it says  `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_11 and Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_11__Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:118)`

Comment: Search for `ImgCodecs.java` file in your project(tap double shift, Android Studio shortcut to search file). In that file search for `imread()` method, to see if it is present? and also note the signature of that method.

Comment: It seems wierd that other OpenCV API's are working fine but `Imgcodecs.imread()`is not :/

Comment: yaa it's present : `public static Mat imread(String filename, int flags)
    {
        
        Mat retVal = new Mat(imread_0(filename, flags));
        
        return retVal;
    }`

Comment: There should be multiple `Mat imread(...)`, implementations I guess. However can you change your code as `Imgcodecs.imread( selectedImagePath, 1);` just to see if this works ?

Comment: Oh I missed it, Have you called `OpenCcLoader.initDebug()` or `OpenCvLoader.initAsync()` as explained in the given answer? This method is responsible for creating the link between Java and native API ?

Answer (score 3):

You hava to initialize OpenCV library before using on Android.

Call below code before use OpenCV

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_11, this, baseLoaderCallback);
```

And then, below method will be callback.

```
  @Override
  public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
       switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                 Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            } break;
            default:
            {
                 super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
       }
  }
```

};